# CSS3 simple Text Animation, overlaps fixed Navigation bar when scrolled, although the content area of the text doesn't?

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

So, it as the title says, I have a fixed position navigation, followed up by a banner and a content area, and I am using `Animate.css` (from github), to style a simple header, in the content area. The header behaves fine when not in an animated state and does not overlaps the navigation upon zooming and scrolling the page, but after the animation it overlaps.

I had the same issue with my banner after animation, but i could sort it our by setting `position:relative;` and `z-index:0`;

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your code, it will help to diagnose possible issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards` seems to solve the problem, it is now working as expected.

I do not understand why the `z-index` manipulation didn't help in this case but it did in the case of banner.